# missing orders in google analytics report api v4

Tags: google-analytics-api

Thera are some order's in GA. I want to get some order's properties (ex. campaign) with GA reporting api v4. I have such a request:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?key=

{YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "reportRequests": [
  {
   "dateRanges": [
    {
     "startDate": "2018-11-14",
     "endDate": "2018-11-16"
    }
   ],
   "pivots": [
    {
     "dimensions": [
      {
       "name": "ga:campaign"
      }
     ],
     "metrics": [
      {
       "expression": "ga:totalValue"
      }
     ]
    }
   ],
   "dimensions": [
    {
     "name": "ga:transactionId"
    }
   ],
   "viewId": "63535262"
  }
 ]
}
```

Certain orders are skipped, an i specify wrong metrics?
Result part, order 1811/430 is not in the list:

```
{
      "dimensions": [
       "1811/429"
      ],
      "metrics": [
       {
        "pivotValueRegions": [
         {
          "values": [
           "6000.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0",
           "0.0"
          ]
         }
        ]
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "dimensions": [
       "1811/431"
      ],
      "metrics": [
       {
        "pivotValueRegions": [
```

However, in the GA itself the order is present and it has a campaign.

Sorry for dummy english, will be very grateful for the answers!

Comment: When building your report in the API you need to be sure to request exactly the same dimensions and metrics as the report you are looking at in the google analytics website.  This is the only way to get the same data.

Comment: Thank you, i solved the problem using a filter:)